# Is their any way get last updated record of key from riak

Tags: riak

Suppose key contains following data
{name:"abc"}

Then I override it with new data
{name:"aaa",grade:"A"} .

Is their any way in riak where I get old data ?  i.e {name:"abc"}

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that without using siblings there is no automated way in Riak to retrieve that last value for a specific key.

The answer to this type of problem is to build a versioning system into your application where you store N number of versions of your key/value pair based on your business needs.